# How to uncoil a Snake model?

Tags: modeling, bones, obj

I bought a model from Cults3d of a python for a project. See attached.

[image]

I want to unwrap the model so I can add some bones or modifiers to wrap the snake on a stick.

Any suggestions on how to approach uncoiling this model?

Or Where Could I find a skilled Modeler to to create a Python model for 3D printing to requirements?

- Mike

Comment: Take care with the use of "Unwrap" here, in Blender it's mostly used for Uv Unwrapping, which is unrelated to your question. It could lead to irrelevant answers and above all, irrelevant search results... Maybe "Straighten" would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, I approved the edit.